# Copy columns vba to new worksheet with offset

Tags: excel, vba

Hey i am really new to vba programming and i have a small issue. 
I am trying to copy columns with offset to a new workbook and worksheet.

I have got the copy function to work but i dont get the offset on my newWorkbook. Just the columns them self. I want to skip firt row in the new sheet.

So i guess this is a easy fix but i cant figure it out. :)
So any help would be very helpful. 
It is the row in code 
        Destination:=targetSheet.Columns(ColumnNumbers(i))

Here is the rest of the code.

```
    Sub columnCopyNEW()

' Copy columns to a new file
Dim BookToCopy As String, BookCopyTo As String

Dim Headers As Variant
Dim ColumnNumbers As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim SourceColumnFind As Range
'Dim targetColumn 

As Range
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet, copySheet As Worksheet

BookToCopy = "book to be copied" 'copy FROM workbook
BookCopyTo = "book that will get the new columns" 'copy TO workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Disables "Screen flashing" between 2 workbooks


Set copySheet = Workbooks(BookToCopy).Worksheets(1)
Set targetSheet = Workbooks(BookCopyTo).Worksheets(1)

Headers = Array("ProductBrand", "ProductCountryOfOrigin", "ProductCustomsTarifNumber", "ItemSEGName30", ItemEnumber) 'Headers from exportfile
ColumnNumbers = Array("E", "AD", "AE", "K", "F") 'array of columns to paste in.

For i = LBound(Headers) To UBound(Headers)
    With copySheet.Rows(1)
        Set SourceColumnFind = .Find(Headers(i), after:=.Cells(1, 1), MatchCase:=True)
    End With


    If Not SourceColumnFind Is Nothing Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        copySheet.Activate
        'copy to new workbook and sheet
         ActiveSheet.Range(SourceColumnFind, ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, SourceColumnFind.Column).End(xlUp).Address).Offset(2).Copy _
         Destination:=targetSheet.Columns(ColumnNumbers(i)) ' This is where i need to put offset(1)
    End If
Next i
 targetSheet.Activate
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turns screenupdating on


End Sub
```

Comment: Unless this is just a weird copy you have As Range floating out there I think it was meant to be part of Dim targetColumn which you commented out.

Comment: I didnt copy correct. So sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destination: `targetSheet.Range(ColumnNumbers(i) & 2)`.